# Merging objects with grouping via Steam API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an object:

```
public class Test {

    private Integer id;
    private String first;
    private String second;
}
```

... and then:

```
Test test1 = new Test(1, "qweqwe", null);
Test test2 = new Test(2, "qweqwe", null);
Test test3 = new Test(3, "qweqwe", null);
Test test4 = new Test(1, null, "dfdsfg");
Test test5 = new Test(2, null, "dfdsfg");
Test test6 = new Test(3, null, "dfdsfg");
```

I want to group objects by id, so I can get something like:

```
List<Test> list = Arrays.asList(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6).stream()
                .someMagicGrouping
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

... and the result would be a list of objects:

- `(1, "qweqwe", "dfdsfg")`
- `(2, "qweqwe", "dfdsfg")`
- `(3, "qweqwe", "dfdsfg")`

All I managed to get by searching and experimenting is `Map<Integer, List<Test>>`, but that's not really what I need. I tried .`collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getId, Collectors.toList()));`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of 'keyed stream' in Java Stream API like in some Big Data processing pipelines, so you'll have to group the result first and stream the values again.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test1 = new Test(1, "qweqwe", null);
    Test test2 = new Test(2, "qweqwe", null);
    Test test3 = new Test(3, "qweqwe", null);
    Test test4 = new Test(1, null, "dfdsfg");
    Test test5 = new Test(2, null, "dfdsfg");
    Test test6 = new Test(3, null, "dfdsfg");

    List<Test> list = Stream.of(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6)
            // collect to Map<String,Test> by ID
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getId)) 
            // stream only the values: Stream<List<Test>>
            .values()
            .stream()
            // reduce by merging fields, assumes data is "correct"
            .map(i -> i.stream().reduce((a, b) -> new Test(
                    a.getId(),
                    a.getFirst() == null ? b.getFirst() : a.getFirst(),
                    a.getSecond() == null ? b.getSecond() : a.getSecond()
            // orElse new because reduce returns an optional in case there is no aggregation result, it won't ever happen if dataset is "correct"
            )).orElse(new Test())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(list);
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class Test {
    private Integer id;
    private String first;
    private String second;
}
```

This does produce the result you require but it is a bit clumsy, and not efficient since the reduce operation has to create a new Test oject every time, I wouldn't say that it is more practical than just using the imperative approach.

Comment: thank you for the answer, atleast i've got some point how it can be done, even though it seems clumsy

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result by using a single Stream `groupBy` and `reducing` collectors. On the other hand, finding out the first non-null value in Java is a bit clumsy (either use `Optional` or a ternary operator):

```java
Collection<Test> list = Stream.of(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6)
    .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getId,
            Collectors.reducing(
                    new Test(), 
                    (a, b) -> new Test(
                            findNonNull(a.getId(), b.getId()),
                            findNonNull(a.getFirst(), b.getFirst()),
                            findNonNull(a.getSecond(), b.getSecond())))))
    .values();
```

```java
private <T> T findNonNull(final T... values) {
    for (T value : values) {
        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Result printed each on a new line:

> ```
> Application.Test(id=1, first=qweqwe, second=dfdsfg)
> Application.Test(id=2, first=qweqwe, second=dfdsfg)
> Application.Test(id=3, first=qweqwe, second=dfdsfg)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just a more refined solution is to create a merge function at the `Test` class and use `Optional.ofNullable` to merge values

```java
public class Test {

  public Test mergeNotNull(Test o2) {
    return new Test(Optional.ofNullable(id).orElse(o2.id),
      Optional.ofNullable(first).orElse(o2.first),
      Optional.ofNullable(second).orElse(o2.second));
  }
}

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Collection<Test> list = Stream.of(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6)
        .collect(groupingBy(Test::getId, reducing(new Test(), Test::mergeNotNull)))
        .values();
}
```

```
[
  Test{id=1, first='qweqwe', second='dfdsfg'}, 
  Test{id=2, first='qweqwe', second='dfdsfg'}, 
  Test{id=3, first='qweqwe', second='dfdsfg'}
]
```